# About partial derivatives.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've been doing some exercises of differentiability, continuity and other properties of some functions of two variables, and I wanted to ask you a simple question. If

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a_1,a_2)\  \exists,\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a_1,a_2)\  \exists
\end{equation}

but
\begin{equation}
\lim_{(x,y)\to (a_1,a_2)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\ne \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a_1,a_2)\ ,
\end{equation}

can I say that the partial derivatives are not continuous at $(a_1,a_2)$, or I have to calculate all of them if I have to study the continuity of the partial derivatives?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can say that the partial derivative by x is not continuous, you practically mentioned that the definition of continuity does not apply here.
On the other hand, you don't know anything about the derivative by y.